# Как поменять иконку папки в GNOME

Tags: linux, gui, gnome

Я хочу поменять иконку ВСЕХ папок на другую, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменить иконку, нужно ее скачать, после зайти в директорию /usr/share/icons/[Название_Вашей_Темы]/places/ удалить файл с названием folder.*, и скопировать недавно скачанный файл, с тем же названием и рассширением, которое было у удаленого файла, после зайти в настройки вашей оболочки (У меня Gnome) и сменить тему иконок на другую и обратно.

Comment: И потом при ближайшем обновлении системы все заменённые картинки перезатрутся после обновления темы. Свою собственную тему лучше класть куда-нибудь в ~/.local/share/icons